# How can I map through the given object to get "value"..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    {
    "confirmed": {
        "value": 104854731,
        "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
    },
    "recovered": {
        "value": 58294751,
        "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/recovered"
    },
    "deaths": {
        "value": 2282535,
        "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/deaths"
    },
    "dailySummary": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily",
    "dailyTimeSeries": {
        "pattern": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/[dateString]",
        "example": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/2-14-2020"
    },
    "image": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/og",
    "source": "https://github.com/mathdroid/covid19",
    "countries": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries",
    "countryDetail": {
        "pattern": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/[country]",
        "example": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/USA"
    },
    "lastUpdate": "2021-02-05T05:22:38.000Z"
    }
    function InfoPanel() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>Infected</Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>Recovered</Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>Deaths</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to display the "value" from "confirmed" key into the "Infected" parameter using map function or anything else. Is there any possible way of doing that or map function only works on arrays.

Comment: Why not just `obj.confirmed.value` ?

Comment: Could you please try to elaborate the question or provide an example of what you have and what you want to get as a result

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: checkout `Object.entries`, `Object.keys`

Answer (score 2):

```
const yourObj = {  
 "confirmed": {      
     "value": 123456789,
     "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
 },
 "deaths": {      
     "value": 99999,
     "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
 },
 "recovered": {      
     "value": 8888,
     "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
 }
}

const desiredKeys = Object.keys(yourObj)
const stats = desiredKeys.reduce((finalResult, desiredKey) => {
    let temp = {}

    temp.category = desiredKey
    temp.value = yourObj[desiredKey].value
    
    finalResult.push(temp);
    
    return finalResult
}, [])

console.log(stats)   //[{category: "confirmed",  value: 123456789}, {  category: "deaths",  value: 9999}, {  category: "recovered",  value: 8888}]
```

```
//InfoPanel
function InfoPanel(){
 return (
   //more code on top
   <Grid container spacing={3}>
     stats.map(stat=> (
       <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
         <Paper className={classes.paper}>{stat.category}: {stat.value}</Paper>
       </Grid>
     ))
   </Grid>
   //more code below
)}
```

Comment: Thanks, This was helpful but I just want to pin point exact "value" from the object . Is there any possible way for that...

Comment: you mean getting the ```value``` in ```confirmed```? Isn't it ```yourObj[confirmed].value``` can do the job? Or you have many keys in ```yourObj```? If so, check my updated answer.

Comment: check my updated answer. I have made 3 keys in the object. See whether it fits your need.

Answer (score 1):

const myObj= {
"confirmed": {
"value": 1234,
"detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
},

"pending": {
"value": 4567,
"detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
},

"final": {
"value": 7890,
"detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
}
}

let value;

Object.keys(myObj).map(function(key, index) {

```
     if(key === 'confirmed'){
     value = myObj[key].value;
     return 
     }
```

})

console.log(value);  // 1234

Comment: I have updated my Question.. Can you tell me more about it...???

Comment: I edited my answer. In this way, you can get the exact value based on the key. Hope this helps!!